# How convert Bitmap Object to Image Object and vice versa in android 'java'

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

### How convert Image obj to Bitmap obj and vice versa?

---

I have a method that get Image object input and return Image object but i want give bitmap object input and then get bitmap object output my code is this:

---

```
public Image edgeFilter(Image imageIn) {
    // Image size
    int width = imageIn.getWidth();
    int height = imageIn.getHeight();
    boolean[][] mask = null;
    Paint grayMatrix[] = new Paint[256];

    // Init gray matrix
    for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++) {
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.rgb(i, i, i));
        grayMatrix[i] = p;
    }
    int [][] luminance = new int[width][height];
    for (int y = 0; y < height ; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width ; x++) {
            if(mask != null && !mask[x][y]){
                    continue;
            }
            luminance[x][y] = (int) luminance(imageIn.getRComponent(x, y), imageIn.getGComponent(x, y), imageIn.getBComponent(x, y));
        }
    }
    int grayX, grayY;
    int magnitude;
    for (int y = 1; y < height-1; y++) {
        for (int x = 1; x < width-1; x++) {

            if(mask != null && !mask[x][y]){
                continue;
            }

            grayX = - luminance[x-1][y-1] + luminance[x-1][y-1+2] - 2* luminance[x-1+1][y-1] + 2* luminance[x-1+1][y-1+2] - luminance[x-1+2][y-1]+ luminance[x-1+2][y-1+2];
            grayY = luminance[x-1][y-1] + 2* luminance[x-1][y-1+1] + luminance[x-1][y-1+2] - luminance[x-1+2][y-1] - 2* luminance[x-1+2][y-1+1] - luminance[x-1+2][y-1+2];

            // Magnitudes sum
            magnitude = 255 - Image.SAFECOLOR(Math.abs(grayX) + Math.abs(grayY));
            Paint grayscaleColor = grayMatrix[magnitude];

            // Apply the color into a new image
            imageIn.setPixelColor(x, y, grayscaleColor.getColor());
        }
    }

    return imageIn;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert an Image object to a Bitmap and the format has been selected as JPEG, then you can accomplish this by using the following code (if it is not a JPEG, then additional conversions will be needed):

```
...
if(image.getFormat() == ImageFormat.JPEG)
{
    ByteBuffer buffer = capturedImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
    byte[] jpegByteData = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
    Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpegByteData, 0, jpegByteData.length, null);
 }
 ...
```

Comment: how about bitmap to image?

Comment: Actually i don't have image object i have a bitmap object and i want pass it to this method and get a filtered bitmap

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html) gives more into on saving images as a png format.

it is difficult to see what you are attempting to do, are you trying to alter this code so it also works for bitmap formats?

here is a [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475482/how-can-i-load-a-bitmap-image-and-manipulate-individual-pixels) of someone doing stuff with bitmap images, should be give you a idea of what other people do

Comment: i don't want open an image file or save an image.I want convert Image object to bitmap object and vice versa. this method have Image input and output i want covert it to bitmap object.